# How to read custom header in IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I would like to authenticate user not just based on username and password, but also based on tenant. I would like to pass tenant as custom header X-Company-Tenant. Can I read this custom header value in ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator in procedure ValidateAsync?

Is it possible to create a middleware on IdentityServer4 to read header from request and pass that value to ValidateAsync?

Comment: Why am I getting down votes, but no comments? If something is wrong with my question, let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET you can inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into anything that comes from DI (as a constructor dependency). This will give you access to the current HTTP context - including the request headers.

That said - you could also post the tenant as a body member and you would get easy access from the context object passed into your validator.